# How to create additional rendering for custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, page-template

Eg I have posts, with url `site.com/post_name/`
I want to make additional posts template to render different layout of the same data, like `site.com/post_name/custom_render/`
So in result I would have 2 urls and 2 layouts for each post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`add_rewrite_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_tag/) and [`add_rewrite_rule`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) functions to first register your custom URL handlers.
Something like

```
add_rewrite_tag( '%custom_render%', 'true' );
add_rewrite_rule(
        '([^/]+)/custom_render/?$',
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]&custom_render=true',
            'top'
    );
```

And then you can us [`template_inclide`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) hook to check if the query param `custom_render` is set, then return the name of the new template.

*Note: You need to flush your rewrite rules after making changes.*

Comment: @Vanyatwo does this solved your problem ?